# Error In contact while Lead conversion

Tags: validation, validation-rule, leads, lead-conversion

While converting lead to I am gettign error "Birthdate is Mandatory in Contact"(validation rule in Contact) Birthdateis the mandatory field in Contact.

but i need to convert lead and create contact without birthdate. How can i achieve this.

there is one setting in lead-->where i can disable the rules to run,but i dont need this solution. Any alternate way?

Comment: looks like you have modified the content.Please add the validation error.I have added the answer based on the question that you asked before edited.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 2 custom fields on both Lead and Contact object and bypass it in validation Rule.

**You can follow below steps:**

1.Create a Custom Field(Type:Checkbox) on lead object lets Say "Lead Convert".Set the Default value to true.

2.Create another Custom Field(Type:Checkbox) on Contact Object Lets Say "IsConvertFromLead".Set the Default value to False.

3.Map Custom Field of Lead "Lead Convert" to Custom Field of Conatct "IsConvertFromLead".

4.In Your Validation Rule of Contact,add "IsConvertFromLead" field and set the value to false.

Follow Above steps.So when you covert your lead to Contact then IsConvertFromLead will set to true and it will help to bypass validation rule.

Let me know if it helps.